# Cannot change prompt in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, prompt

I tried this
`PS1='\u:\W\$ '` --- it does change prompt temporarily, but it does not show my name or current directory. Instead, it displayed exactly what it is `\u:\W\$`

I replace it with the current PS1 in .bashrc, but the prompt did not change at all, even after I exit and log in again.

I found something that works temporarily:
`export PS1='$USER@$(hostname):$PWD$ '`
but this shows the all directory. I only want to see something like `~\myDir`
Moreover, I replaced this with the current PS1 in .bashrc but it does not change the prompt at all.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what is your shell? looks like it is not bash

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in a terminal to open ~/.bashrc file:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

In your `~/.bashrc`, find the following section:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Remove the @\h, and replace the \w with an uppercase \W, so that it becomes:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\W\$ '
fi
```

Save, exit, close terminal and start another to see the result.

Comment: Let me know if it is not working for you.

Comment: Hi Ravi, it did not work :(

Comment: still the same issue?

Comment: right, not change anything

Comment: Please refe this link:- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1791780

Comment: This link will also help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2044898

Comment: thanks Ravi, but I actually look through links but they do not help.

Comment: Refer this link also. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15643/i-changed-my-hostname-why-is-my-bash-ps1-prompt-unchanged

Answer (score 0):

In your line try using @ instead of : after u as in \u@

They must be surrounded in single quotes when they are used as in the following example:

```
$ echo $PS1

$

$ export PS1='\u@\h:\w$ '

me@example.com:~$ # new prompt

me@example.com:~$
```